# Mongodb nested array matching

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a document resulting from a graphLookup operation that looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": "5cda6b0166a8b255c58e9597",
  "updateTime": "1231731025000",
  "txId": "f4184fc596403b9d638783cf57adfe4c75c605f6356fbc91338530e9831e9e16",
  "outputSum": "5000000000",
  "inputSum": 0,
  "inputs": [
    {
      "fromAddress": "12cbQLTFMXRnSzktFkuoG3eHoMeFtpTu3S",
      "amount": "5000000000",
      "chunksSize": 0
    }
  ],
  "outputs": [
    {
      "out": "1Q2TWHE3GMdB6BZKafqwxXtWAWgFt5Jvm3",
      "amount": 1000000000
    },
    {
      "out": "12cbQLTFMXRnSzktFkuoG3eHoMeFtpTu3S",
      "amount": "4000000000"
    }
  ],
  "txHierarchy": [
    {
      "_id": "5cda6b0266a8b255c58e959d",
      "updateTime": "1231790660000",
      "txId": "828ef3b079f9c23829c56fe86e85b4a69d9e06e5b54ea597eef5fb3ffef509fe",
      "outputSum": "2800000000",
      "inputSum": 0,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "fromAddress": "12cbQLTFMXRnSzktFkuoG3eHoMeFtpTu3S",
          "amount": "2800000000",
          "chunksSize": 0
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "out": "1ByLSV2gLRcuqUmfdYcpPQH8Npm8cccsFg",
          "amount": 1000000000
        },
        {
          "out": "12cbQLTFMXRnSzktFkuoG3eHoMeFtpTu3S",
          "amount": 1800000000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cda7673501a1a441ac4cb08",
      "updateTime": "1289939967000",
      "txId": "ea44e97271691990157559d0bdd9959e02790c34db6c006d779e82fa5aee708e",
      "outputSum": 1000000000,
      "inputSum": 0,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "fromAddress": "1Q2TWHE3GMdB6BZKafqwxXtWAWgFt5Jvm3",
          "amount": 1000000000,
          "chunksSize": 0
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "out": "15kDhRAcpgsugmh6mQsTcCHdvbsuYncEEV",
          "amount": 1000000000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cda6b0266a8b255c58e9598",
      "updateTime": "1231740133000",
      "txId": "a16f3ce4dd5deb92d98ef5cf8afeaf0775ebca408f708b2146c4fb42b41e14be",
      "outputSum": "4000000000",
      "inputSum": 0,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "fromAddress": "12cbQLTFMXRnSzktFkuoG3eHoMeFtpTu3S",
          "amount": "4000000000",
          "chunksSize": 0
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "out": "1DUDsfc23Dv9sPMEk5RsrtfzCw5ofi5sVW",
          "amount": 1000000000
        },
        {
          "out": "12cbQLTFMXRnSzktFkuoG3eHoMeFtpTu3S",
          "amount": "3000000000"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cda6b0266a8b255c58e959a",
      "updateTime": "1231742062000",
      "txId": "12b5633bad1f9c167d523ad1aa1947b2732a865bf5414eab2f9e5ae5d5c191ba",
      "outputSum": "2900000000",
      "inputSum": 0,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "fromAddress": "12cbQLTFMXRnSzktFkuoG3eHoMeFtpTu3S",
          "amount": "2900000000",
          "chunksSize": 0
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "out": "13HtsYzne8xVPdGDnmJX8gHgBZerAfJGEf",
          "amount": 100000000
        },
        {
          "out": "12cbQLTFMXRnSzktFkuoG3eHoMeFtpTu3S",
          "amount": "2800000000"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cda6b0266a8b255c58e9599",
      "updateTime": "1231740736000",
      "txId": "591e91f809d716912ca1d4a9295e70c3e78bab077683f79350f101da64588073",
      "outputSum": "3000000000",
      "inputSum": 0,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "fromAddress": "12cbQLTFMXRnSzktFkuoG3eHoMeFtpTu3S",
          "amount": "3000000000",
          "chunksSize": 0
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "out": "1LzBzVqEeuQyjD2mRWHes3dgWrT9titxvq",
          "amount": 100000000
        },
        {
          "out": "12cbQLTFMXRnSzktFkuoG3eHoMeFtpTu3S",
          "amount": "2900000000"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to get the txIds that match: txHierarchy.inputs.fromAddress and outputs.out

I try simple mongo db query and actually I let it work with client iteration but I'm asking if mongo can give to me a fast way.

Can someone help me?

Comment: how do you retrieve this data?

Comment: can you update the question with what you had tried..?whatever mongo query you wrote..!